# Can apollo-android be used as a java client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, apollo-android

I'm working on a spring boot app that needs to talk to the Github GraphQl API. Can apollo-android be used for this purpose? Since all of it's scarce documentation available as well as the sample project is written with android in mind, I'm not sure.

Comment: The Android-specific references appear to be isolated in the `apollo-android-support` module. I do not know how easy it is to fork this project and create a replacement module that does not use Android APIs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maintainer here. You can absolutely use Apollo-Android in a java only project. There is only 1 module/artifact that is android specific which is not required. The android artifact simply brings in android specific threading models.  Come join our slack if you need more help :-) http://www.apollostack.com/#slack

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](https://github.com/Cox-Automotive/apollo-client-maven-plugin/blob/master/apollo-client-maven-plugin-tests/src/main/graphql/queries/GetBooks.graphql) maven plugin. It would be nice if you could make a sample project that uses apollo-android in spring boot.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to use in spring boot?